# How to correctly put the root of a Forest tree in a custom position?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am trying to draw a simple tree using `forest`. A simplified version is the following:
[image]

Now I need to reduce the horizontal space occupied by the figure. My idea is moving the root node above Node A, as all the space below the root is left unused.
I tried  manually adjusting the positioning of the root before the tree is drawn, but what I get is:

[image]

I would need a different, more complex, positioning of the edges from the root to its children (as highlighted by the hand-drawn red line in the picture).

Any advice to do so would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code for this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
forked edges,
       for tree={
           calign=first,
           anchor=west,
           fit=rectangle,
           draw=gray,
           grow'=0,
           edge={gray,line width=1pt},
       },
  [Root, before drawing tree={y+=3.8em, x+=3em}, 
    [{Node A}
        [A1]
        [A2]
        [A3]
    ]
    [{Node B}
        [B1]
        [B2]
        [B3]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can do this changing the direction of growth. There are some examples on here if you can find them ....

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I solved my problem as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
forked edges,
       for tree={
           calign=first,
           anchor=west,
           fit=rectangle,
           draw=gray,
           grow'=0,
           if level=0 {parent anchor=south, child anchor=parent}{},
           if level=1 {edge={red,line width=1pt},edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)|-(.child anchor)}}{  edge={gray,line width=1pt} }
       },
  [Root, before drawing tree={y+=3.8em, x+=2em}, 
    [{Node A}
        [A1]
        [A2]
        [A3]
    ]
    [{Node B}
        [B1]
        [B2]
        [B3]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Note that I also had to slightly move the root node to the left.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi,dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
          forked edges,
%         /.style={
%           for tree={parent anchor=children},
%           for descendants={child anchor=parent,forked edge}
%}
        for tree={
            calign=first,
%           parent anchor=east,
%           child anchor=east,
            fit=rectangle,
            draw=gray,
            grow'=0,
            edge={gray,line width=1pt},edge path'={(!u.parent anchor)--($(!u.parent anchor)+(4pt,0pt)$) -- ++(0pt,-15pt) -| ($(-2pt,0pt)+(.child anchor)$)--(.child anchor)},
        },
        [Root, before drawing tree={y+=3.8em, x+=3em}, 
        [{Node A}
        [A1]
        [A2]
        [A3]
        ]
        [{Node B}
        [B1]
        [B2]
        [B3]
        ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely helps. However, the edge looks a bit weird. I updated the question to show what i would like to achieve eventually.